# What's Kik's level of WebSocket support on android devices that don't natively support them?

Tags: websocket, kik

I've got a project using WebSockets that I want to possibly integrate with Kik. Is it going to be work on the Android platforms that don't natively support WebSockets? I know there are many posts here on SO with native android code to inject WebSockets into the webview. Have any of these been implemented? What is the suggested workaround if not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets are natively supported on Android 4.4+. On older operating systems it is normally recommended to use XHR polling or other mechanisms.

I would suggest using Socket.io as it is a very mature library for this kind of technology with backward compatibility modes going back to pretty old browsers.

http://socket.io

Comment: I'm running with socket.io, so I gave it a chance in kik. It crashes. I can run in browser, but kik crashes. I have a log but not sure how to file bugs for you guys and I can't post it here.